# iOS: Advantage of fresh install over backup restore?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup

Are there any advantages in setting up a new iPhone from scratch over restoring a backup of the old one?

I have now my third iPhone and I always used the backup of the predecessor to get it set up. Do I carry any clutter with me that makes it better to do a fresh install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Alex from Reincubate, I work on the iPhone Backup Extractor.

Setting up your iPhone from scratch will mean that you lose your personalized settings, while restoring from previous backup will revert the settings to the moment of the backup. If you have nothing against taking it all over again with your iPhone you should set as new, but if you are in a hurry and want to speed the process up restore from backup.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don’t jailbreak, restoring a new phone from a backup will not cause any problems.

Sometimes, using software that bypasses iTunes (e.g. DiskAid) or edits the backups (e.g. iExplorer) will cause problems.